# Commenting functions in different file with Doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I need to comment a set of functions in several C++ projects. Goal of comments are creating an HTML documentation with Doxygen. Some of project files (both .h and .cpp) are automatically written by a kind of bot and generation procedure cannot be changed. I would like been able to comment functions declared and defined in such files. I was wondering if it is possible comment a function in a different file in order to allow Doxygen building HTML and diagram files.

Here it is an example:

*File1.h* (automatically generated)

```
void foo(int a);
```

*File1.cpp* (automatically generated)

```
#include "File1.h"
void foo(int a)
{
   /*Function body*/
}
```

*main.cpp* (handly written, can write whatever I want)

```
#include "File1.h"

/**
Some proper comments for documenting function foo declared in File1.h and defined in File1.cpp
*/
int main(int a)
{
   /*Main body*/
}
```

Thank you for your help, suggestions and hints.
Best things.

Comment: I could but I am hesitant to write an answer, because the information is on the frontpage of doxygens manual (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html -> "Documentation at other places"). Please do some research before asking

Comment: to be fair, it isnt the frontpage, but the frontpage of the "Documenting the code" chapter

Answer (score 2):

After a bit I found answer to the question.
It is possibile placing comment to any function or member function wherever wished. It is enough adding @fn command to define the function or member you are commenting.

Completing example started in my question, main.cpp file will look like this:

```
#include "File1.h"

    /** @fn void myclass::foo(int a)
     *  @brief A member function.
     *  @param a: input parameter.
     */
int main(int a)
{
   /*Main body*/
}
```

If your function is not a class member, just write like this:

```
/** @fn void foo(int a)
*  @brief A member function.
*  @param a: input parameter.
*/
```

Thank you at  [idclev 463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/idclev-463035818) for your comment and help.